# XCUITest cannot detect the accessibility id of my dynamically generated tableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I am writing  UI tests using XCUIApplication. I am testing for selected Index on a cell row. When I run the tests I am unable to get the text of the selected index. However I am able to click on the selected row but using the static text of the bottom tableView. This happens when there is a tableViewController underneath. I am trying to add a ViewController with a tableView on top of another TableViewController. The tableViewController underneath is generated using storyboard but the above viewController is dynamically generated.

Setup: I am using an xib for the row for the tableView and i am using a custom UITableViewCell with a label and and image. Both Label and image have accessibility turned on but not the cell. I have tried turning on accessibility on the cell and still didn't work.

This is my test

```
//the BoxListTable is my ViewController that is on top
// I added the following code in that viewController:
   self.view.isAccessibilityElement = true
   self.view.accessibilityIdentifier = "BoxListTable"

//I also added these for the tableView but it doesn't show up in my tests
   tableView.accessibilityIdentifier = "tableview"
   tableView.isAccessibilityElement = true

//my test is the following

 XCUIApplication().tables["BoxListTable"].tap()
```

when I run this test the test click on the full tableView but cannot get any of the static texts. It also cannot get any cells or the tableview. 
    po XCUIApplication.tables["BoxListTable"].cells.count 
    it return 0. 
    //I tried
      XCUIApplication.tables["BoxListTable"].element.children(matching:   .other)
    return 0

Can you please let me know why I cannot see the accessibilityIdentifier even though it is set.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with the, otherwise great,  [SkyFloatingLabelTextField](https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField). I can't access any of the subviews presented by it...

Comment: What do you get when you do `po XCUIApplication().tables`? And what is the class type of `self.view` on your view controller?

Comment: @Oletha When I do po XUIApplication().tables , I get all the tables that are currently displayed and it doesn't include the the table view that is in view. I can only get a reference to the tableView below. The  XCUIApplication().tables.count returns 1

Answer (score 7):

First of all, if you turn on `isAccessibilityElement` flag on parent view (in your case it is the view of `BoxListTable`) all of its children won't be accessible. The same applies to `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell`. But you can set their `accessibilityIdentifiers` and they will be visible for all the UI element, even those with `isAccessibilityElement` evaluating to `false`.

So there is this pure XCTest version but it will work only for cells already loaded (all of the lazily loaded cells won't be available) and may be obstructed by keyboard or navigation bar. Also if you look for content of element without performing any action on it framework itself won't scroll to this element. So checking if view `exists` will pass but `isHittable` will fail as the element may not be out of an area user can see.

```swift
let app = XCIUApplication()
let selectedCell: XCUIElement = table.cells.element(matching: NSPredicate(format: "isSelected == true"))
selectedCell.tap() // If you want to make sure framework will scroll to it.
selectedCell.staticTexts["yourText"]
// or
selectedCell.staticTexts.element(boundBy: index)
```

I would encourage you to try using [AutoMate](https://github.com/PGSSoft/AutoMate) library that can save you all above troubles.

```swift
let app = XCIUApplication()
let selectedCell: XCUIElement = table.cells.element(matching: NSPredicate(format: "isSelected == true"))
XCTAssertFalse(selectedCell.isVisible) // `isVisible` checks if element exists in hierarchy and is visible to the user.
table.swipe(to: .down, untilVisible: selectedCell, from: app)
XCTAssertTrue(selectedCell.isVisible)
```

To see how all of this methods work, please, check the example app I've made [>>here<<](https://github.com/dzoanb/find-selected-cell).

If you find any problems with `isSelected` property on `XCUIElement` you should check my answer to [>>this question<<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935745/ui-tests-isselected-is-always-returning-false/43274271#43274271). As you can see in the example app I had this problem (Xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)).

Comment: BTW, setting `isAccessibilityElement = false` really made my day here on a related UI testing issue... thanks a lot for the tip :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, setting isAccessibilityElement = false on the parent view did the trick.

Comment: @dzoanb Thank you for your help, setting isAccessibilityElement = false . I thought it did the trick but when the bottom TableView is empty, I get this `XCUIApplication.tables["Empty list"]`. If there are rows on the bottom table it selects     `XCUIApplication.tables.children(matching:.cell).element(boundBy:2).button["detailButton"].tap()`. However this selection is for the bottom cell but it gets the hotpoint on the top cell, but not the row index.

Comment: @user2263712  I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Do you have 2 tables in one view? `XCUIApplication.tables.children(matching:.cell).element(boun‌​dBy:2).button["detai‌​lButton"].tap()` I'm afraid it will search through both tables and get all elements. Then if you are using element(boundBy: Int) it puts all cells in one array and takes the one on index 2. But I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. Can you give me more details about view hierarchy and which cell you want to select/what do you want to read from the cell? Try to edit your question with new details. I'll try to help.